# Abelian variety corresponding to a vector space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, surfaces, monodromy, cycles

I would like to know what the following statement means:

"Let $B_t$ be the Abelian subvariety in $J_t$ corresponding to the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector subspace $H^1(C_t,\mathbb{Q})_{van}$ in the space $H^1(C_t,\mathbb{Q})\simeq H^1(J_t,\mathbb{Q})$".

Here $r_t:C_t\rightarrow S$ is the embedding of the smooth connected curve $C_t$ in the surface $S$, $J_t$ is the Jacobian of the curve $C_t$, and $(r_t)_*:H^1(C_t,\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow H^3(S,\mathbb{Q})$ is the Gysing homomorphism in cohomology groups associated to $r_t$.

It is in page 9 of the following paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04187v2

Comment: $r_t:H^1(C_t,\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow H^3(S,\mathbb{Q})$ is a morphism of Hodge structures, so its kernel $H^1(C_t,\mathbb{Q})_{van}$ carries a weight 1 Hodge structure, corresponding to an Abelian subvariety of $JC_t$. In more concrete term, it is the neutral component of the kernel of $(r_t)_{*}: JC_t\rightarrow \operatorname{Alb}(S) $.

Comment: Thank you @abx  !!!. Any reference for "Hodge structure corresponding to an Abelian variety".

Comment: You may look for instance at Voisin's *Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry*, § 7.2.2.